# WC Application context data is nil, Apple Watch, WatchConnectivity, Xcode 14

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, xcode14

isReachable = true
activationState = 2
Profiles and identification are fine

**What am I doing wrong?**

**This Model for iOS target: **

final class ConnectivityiOSModel: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

```
let session = WCSession.default

static let shared = ConnectivityiOSModel()

override private init() {
    super.init()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

func send(message: [String: Any]) {
    guard WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled else {
        print("Connection: watch app is not installed")
        return
    }
    session.sendMessage(message) { _ in }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(
            "Connection: error \(error.localizedDescription)"
        )
    } else {
        // These print calls are just for debugging.
        // activationState values re
        // notActivated = 0, inactive = 1, activated = 2
        print(
            "Connection: activationState = \(activationState.rawValue)"
        )
        print(
            "Connection: reachable? \(session.isReachable)"
        )
    }
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    session.activate()
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    session.activate()
}
```

}

**This for watchOS target:**

final class ConnectivityWatchOSModel: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate, ObservableObject {
let session = WCSession.default

```
static let shared = ConnectivityWatchOSModel()

override private init() {
    super.init()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
}


public func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any]) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .messageReceived, object: nil)
}
```

}

I'm trying to send from iOS app to watch some info in active state, but get this issue

Comment: Your code does not show how you call ConnectivityiOSModel.send(). I suspect your  message ([String: Any]) is nil/empty/invalid. Did you provide an encoder for your info object?